# Calculate the length of the arguments

Tags: c, string, for-loop

Code:

```
int my_strlen(char *string){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++);
    return i;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int length;
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        length = my_strlen(argv[1]);

    }
    printf("Length of the command line args: %d\n", length);
}
```

The output:

```
$ ./a.out guy oneguy
$ Length of the command line args: 6
```

For some reason, it only counted the last arguments, and ignored the others. I was expecting to get 10 (length).

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Initialise `length` to zero and change `length = my_strlen(argv[i]);` to `length += my_strlen(argv[i]);` Also note the change from `1` to `i`.

Comment: "For some reason"? The reason is that that is exactly what you expressed that you wanted to, in your code. :)

Comment: Is there any reason you don't use `strlen`?

Comment: @Axalo No reason at all. I just wanted to try the other way, just for practicing. I know the strlen function exist.

Comment: @user4533813 The real thing is better, since it uses `const char *` and `size_t`. No reason you can't do that, too ... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int length = 0; // Don't forget to initialize to 0.
for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) { // Start from index 0, not 1, to loop through every argument.
    length += my_strlen(argv[i]); // Use i as index to argv to access each argument one by one.
                                  // Add result of my_strlen to length.
}
```

Comment: Oh, the reason I start on 1, is because of the first arguments. For example, `$ ./a.out args1 args2 \0` So the first index [0] is a.out, so I ignored that. So I start at index 1.

Comment: @user4533813 Oh you're right, completely forgot that. 1 it is then.

Answer (score 0):

- Point 1. You never added the previous value of `length` to the next value(s).
- Point 2. You never initialized `length`.
- Point 3. for all the values of `i`, you used `argv[1]`, not `argv[i]`.
- Point 4. with an input of `./a.out guy oneguy`, how you'll get `10`?

use something like

```
length = 0;     // initialize
```

and

```
length += my_strlen(argv[i]);    // add up the length, use i as index.
```

P.S - I don't think the name of the binary should be counted as command line argument, so starting at index 1 iseems correct to me but finally, it's upto you. [There is no right or wrong here, own preference, based on the _print statement] :-)

Comment: `strlen("guy oneguy")` is 10.

Comment: @mch Sir, but isn't `strlen("guy") + strlen("oneguy")` is the case we're looking at here, atleast as per OP's logic?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I did use the strlen for fun. I am keep getting the 9 instead of 10. I did: `length += strlen(argv[i]);` in forloop under main. I changed int length to size_t length.

Comment: this was only a hint why someone could think that the result should be 10. You are right that the program does not work like this. @user4533813 9 is the correct answer, because the space will be removed, you get "guy" and "oneguy" without space.